# PHP PDO prepare() prepared statements not working, but query() works

Tags: php, database, pdo, sqlite

Having trouble getting these PDO prepared statements to work. Working with PHP 7.0.9 on Windows / MAMP and SQLite here.

PHP PDO driver pdo_sqlite installed version `3.8.10.2`

Anyone see what am I doing wrong here?

This works as expected:

```
$st = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `e48` WHERE `parallel` >= 4000 AND `parallel` <= 4010");
$results = $st->fetchAll();
```

This does not work, and gives zero results:

```
$st = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `e48` WHERE `parallel` >= :x AND `parallel` <= :y");
$st->execute(array(':x' => 4000, ':y' => 4010));
$results = $st->fetchAll();
```

This also does not work:

```
$st = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `e48` WHERE `parallel` >= 4000 AND `parallel` <= :y");
$st->execute(array(':y' => 4010));
$results = $st->fetchAll();
```

And ends up giving me the same results as:

```
SELECT * FROM `e48` WHERE `parallel` >= 4000
```

P.S Also tested in Linux virtual machine web server with same results.

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php and see what are the errors

Comment: Also check the answer here, to make sure you've configured PDO correctly to detect errors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584788/php-pdo-sqlite-prepared-statement-issues

Comment: Tried setting attributes `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` and also `$pdo->errorInfo()` but they show nothing.

Comment: @u_mulder The first `query()` method actually works, it's the others below it that don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked it out.

I was using the `TEXT` [SQLite datatype](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html) for the `parallel` column, and it works when I switched it to `REAL` (they are all floating point numbers). So the value in the database was previously stored as (preferred) text strings.

After changing it to `REAL`, the prepared statements now work.

Ref: [Type Conversions Prior To Comparison](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#type_conversions_prior_to_comparison)

---

Why did `$pdo->query("SELECT * FROM e48 WHERE parallel >= 4000 AND parallel <= 4010")` work?

> If one operand has INTEGER, REAL or NUMERIC affinity and the other operand has TEXT or BLOB or no affinity then NUMERIC affinity is applied to other operand.

The right hand operand is treated as having `NUMERIC` affinity, so comparison works as expected.

---

Why didn't `$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM e48 WHERE parallel >= :x AND parallel <= :y")` work?

> If one operand has TEXT affinity and the other has no affinity, then TEXT affinity is applied to the other operand.

With PHP PDO combined with SQLite, the right hand side operand is queried as having **no affinity** at all, so the comparison is treated as having `TEXT` affinity, which in turn becomes a no-op comparison.

Answer (score -1):

```
$array=array('x' => 4000, 'y' => 4010);    
$st = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `e48` WHERE `parallel` >= :x AND `parallel` <= :y");
$st->execute($array);
$results = $st->fetchAll();
```